# Tag User group knowing only name with a bot on slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

On slack - I can tag a user directly from my both with the following text syntax :

```
hello Francois <@francois>
```

I would like to do the same with a group (unfortunately my app only know the group name not the group ID). Is there a syntax to do so - the following syntax does not work :

```
hello group <@group>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "group".

1. Private channels are called groups by the Slack API (e.g.
   [`groups.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.list))
2. Users can be assigned to functional groups called usergroups
   internally by the Slack api (paid Slack only, e.g.
   [`usergroups.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/usergroups.list))

For 1) @mention will not work. Instead you can send a `<!channel>` into the private channel for the same effect.

For 2) the syntax is `<!subteam^ID|handle>`

See an excerpt of the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) on how use them:

> For paid account there is an additional command for User Groups that
>   follows the format . (subteam is literal text. ID
>   and handle are replaced with the details of the group.) These indicate
>   a User Group message, and should cause a notification to be displayed
>   by the client. User Group IDs can be determined from the
>   usergroups.list API endpoint. For example, if you have a User Group
>   named happy-peeps with ID of S012345, then you would use the command
>    to mention that user group in a
>   message.

If you only have the usergroup name and need the ID you can use `usergroups.list` to get the corresponding ID.

Comment: Yes we are in case 2 but @group does not work we somehow can only get it to work with the group ID but we do not have it (our groups have a special naming convention so our application can build the group name but does not know the group ID unfortunately)

Comment: I am using a free tier Slack, so I can not test this. But if it works with IDs and your app can generate the group names, why not use usergroups.list to convert names to usergroup IDs and then use those?

Comment: I now found the correct answer in the docs and corrected my post. Sorry I got it wrong the first time.

Comment: Ok thank you - it confirms it is only possible with group ID.

Comment: I added the info about how to convert names to IDs with your app

Comment: So how exactly can I notify a user group?
If the url is: http://myslackhost.com/messages/DEEA0CR5J/groups/SEHM37R33/
Do I simply use the ID like this:
 Hey <!SEHM37R33> check it out! 
?

Comment: Not exactly. As it described in the answer the syntax is `<!subteam^ID|handle>`. Idk if the handle is optional, I would include it to be sure. Also I would not try to extract the group ID from a URL. Thas is more like a hack. Its better to call the API method `usergroups.list`, which will return a list of all groups with their IDs.

Comment: Got it. it wasn't clear that the subteam^ bit is supposed to be literal text, I thought it was something like <!SEHM37R33|@my-group-name>